# Bind nulls into prepared statement

Tags: sql, groovy, null, sybase

I have this code:

```
String updText = "update table set varcharPar=?, floatPar=?, datePar=?, intPar=? where id=7"

def updateCounts = sql.withBatch(1, updText) { ps ->
    def args = [Types.NULL, Types.NULL, Types.NULL, Types.NULL]
    ps.addBatch(args)
}
```

And when I try to update it doesn't work with varchar parameter, gives me

> ```
> Caught: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Implicit conversion 
> from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed. 
> Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
> ```

It works on int, float and dates. How can I solve this?

If I put null instead of Types.NULL it doesn't work with float.

Comment: What's the use of resultList? What is args? Where and how do you bind arguments?

Comment: sorry, I was modifying my code to make it simpler, changed the code, adding args to the batch

Comment: Types.NULL is an integer whose value is 0. So you're effectively setting all your parameters to 0. You should pass null. I understand that this doesn't work. But what does that mean, precisely? Post the complete exception stack trace, always.

Comment: If I pass null I get  Caught: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Implicit conversion from datatype VARCHAR' to 'FLOAT' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: In that case, bind each parameter explicitly (with ps.setString(), etc.) and then call addBatch().